# Undefined error when trying to use ngDialog

Tags: angularjs

I used bower to install the ngDialog module- see [here](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) I am trying to instantiate the module in my app.js file with the rest of my dependencies, like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngDialog',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives',
    'myApp.controllers',

]);
```

but when I build the app and try to open it in a browser, I get a blank page and an error saying:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngDialog due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngDialog' is not available! You either misspelled the ...
```

Can anyone advise why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is an indication you did not include that javascript in your index.html file.

You have a javascript file that defines ngDialog, make sure it was loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your controller is not taking `ngDialog` as a dependency, so it is not available at runtime... Please check you do something like:

```
app.controller('YourController', function($scope, ..., ngDialog) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: The clue here is `Failed to instantiate module myApp` which says there is a missing dependency.  The error you are indicating not include myApp in the message.