# ngDialog not working with 'external' controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=public%2Fmodule%2FfileManagement%2FFileController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined)  when the [ng-dialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) pops-up.
Here is the function that pops the dialog :

```
var dialog = ngDialog.open({
        template: 'public/module/fileManagement/filePopUp.tpl.html',
        scope: $scope,
        controller : 'FileController',
        $event: $event
    });
```

and here is the controller's code :

```
var fileModule = angular.module('fileModule', []);
fileModule.controller('FileController', function($scope, ngDialog){
var img = {name:'a',description:'a',type:'d'};
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.img = img;
}
$scope.init();});
```

The result in the pop-up is as shown below :

```
nom: {{img.name}}
```

Notes :

- I tested it with a controller that works with no problem outside the dialog.
- Here is an 'official' [example](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/example/index.html) (line 202) of a controller used in an ngDialog pop (line 110)
- I already added the js file to the index.html as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22765283/2678755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **runTarm**, i realised the difference between the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5nWJfHf0k5n2reFqcCDL?p=preview) implementation and mine :

I created a module (which was not the main module):

`var fileModule = angular.module('fileModule', []);`

and added the controller to that module :

`fileModule.controller('FileController', function(){...});`

runTarm added the controller to the main module so it worked well. See his [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5nWJfHf0k5n2reFqcCDL?p=preview).

In order for my implementation to work, i needed to inject the `'fileModule'` to the main module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngDialog','fileModule']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to change this line:

```
controller : 'public/module/fileManagement/FileController',
```

to just this:

```
controller : 'FileController',
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5nWJfHf0k5n2reFqcCDL?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've included an example plunker in the answer. Please have a look at it, you may find a clue why your code doesn't work.